# MariaDB node.js script throws ER_LOCAL_INFILE_WRONG_FILENAME error when trying to load data into table from local XML file

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb

I have a node.js script which is connecting to a local MariaDB server, creating some tables, and then attempting to load some data into them by executing a SQL query like this:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\path\\to\\some_data.xml'
INTO TABLE some_data
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<data>';
```

The script fails with an error like:

```
SqlError: (conn=60, no: 45034, SQLState: 45034) LOCAL INFILE wrong filename. 'C:\path\to\some_data.xml' doesn't correspond to query LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\path\\to\\some_data.xml'
INTO TABLE some_data
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<data>';. Query cancelled. Check for malicious server / proxy
```

The node.js script code is like:

```
const pathToXmlFile = path.resolve(__dirname, '../some_data.xml')
   .replace(/\\/g, '\\\\');
   // .replace(/\\/g, '/'); 
// none of the above work, and neither does no escaping at all
query = `LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '${pathToXmlFile}'
         INTO TABLE some_data
         ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<data>';`;
```

I tried escaping the path with forward slashes (I'm running the script through Git Bash), the error remains the same, only the way the path is displayed changes. I have set `permitLocalInfile: 'true'` on the MariaDB client connection and `local_infile=1` on both the `[mysqld]` and `[client]` sections of `my.ini`. The node.js connection user has the FILE privilege.

Node version is 16.13.0, MariaDB npm module version is 2.5.5, all running on the same machine with Windows 10 (MariaDB server too, on localhost).

**The above query works perfectly fine when executed from HeidiSQL.**

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This seems like a string escaping problem. Could you provide the Node.js code you used to test this? It would greatly help if the actual code was available.

Comment: I have added a code snippet. As I wrote, I think I tried all possible string escaping combinations but maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 1):

I've create a mariadb bug for that : https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJS-181

As a workaround, you might use "/" in place of "\": using "C:/path/to/some_data.xml" won't be escaped avoiding this bug

Comment: Thanks! As I wrote in the description, I tried escaping the path in all possible ways, including forward slashes (unix-style) as you suggested. It doesn't work either way 

Comment: Upon closer investigation, the bug (if any) seems to be with the npm module for mariadb, not mariadb itself. So you should probably close that.

https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-nodejs/blob/519e4ab1a87c40cf1c0bbd75d1377baecf944959/lib/cmd/resultset.js#L520

Comment: And this is the particular method which is testing the validity. I am looking into it, doing some tests.
https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-nodejs/blob/519e4ab1a87c40cf1c0bbd75d1377baecf944959/lib/misc/parse.js#L1009

Comment: I have submitted a new issue with the node.js connector, please close the one above:

https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-nodejs/issues/183

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's a bug with the `mariadb` node connector, I have opened an issue here:

https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-nodejs/issues/183

In the meantime, I have tried the `mysql2` and `mysql` connectors, the first doesn't seem to support the `permitLocalInfile: 'true'` connection option, so I switch to the standard `mysql` connector and everything works fine (with a few changes in the code because of slight differences in method calling).

If the bug in the `mariadb` connector is fixed, I will update the answer here.